# How to display the 1st value of drop down list as default in Excel VBA Macros?

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code to display the values in the list and I want to display the 1st value of dropdown as default so please help me on this.

```
    With Range("C" & r).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="CBP,IBP,ISN,LIP,MCR,MTS"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Comment: `Range("C" & r).Value = "CBP"`?

Comment: Yes it helps if I know the values but sometime I am getting values from different sheet

Comment: Assuming that your data validation cell is Cr, maybe try like this : `v = Range(Range("C" & r).Validation.Formula1).Value....
Range("C" & r).Value = v(1, 1)`